# htaccess remove the duplicate names in the urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this [page](http://healingstreamsusa.org/healing/life-applications.html) and if you scroll to the middle of the page you will see many links that all have duplicate names like for example

```
http://healingstreamsusa.org/healing/healing/good-grief.html
http://healingstreamsusa.org/healing/healing/forgiveness-not-option.html
```

As you can see there are two healing/healing instead of the one healing/ so the urls are all breaking and there are many sitewide...The client made all the urls relative instead of absolute and now he needs an htaccess that will remove the duplicates in the middle....here is what i have and its doesnt do the redirect as i expected....am i missing something

```
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_URI) ^/healing/healing[/]?
RewriteRule (.*) http://healingstreamsusa.org/healing? [R=301,L]
```

Tried all these.....

```
RewriteRule /about/about/(.+)$ /about/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule /about/images/(.+)$ /images/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule /healing/images/stories/(.+)$ /images/stories/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule /healing/healing/(.+)$ /healing/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^healing/healing/([^/]*)$   /healing/$1
```

Any idea why this would not work....

Comment: Fix the page, don't add stupid htaccess rules to do worthless tasks that shouldn't exist in the first place.

Comment: its not my call....the client wants that....

Comment: its many pages ...not just this one...they just want a quick fix

Comment: Quick fixes are not better fixes. If he wants to build his own pages, he needs to learn how to build them *properly*.

Comment: If you can, do what anumuson said! but I posted answer!

Comment: Do you have a `RewriteEngine On` line at the beginning?

Comment: I imagine the origin of the problem is they have a link like "healing/grief.php" and am wondering why couldn't you just fix the relative url's to start with / eg "/healing/grief.php" making the rewrite unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^healing/healing/([^/]*)$   healing/$1
RewriteRule ^about/about/([^/]*)   about/$1
```

Comment: @Tamer you have to create one rule for each one!